# Aurelia validation in activate method

Tags: aurelia

I have a validation rules set up and they work.

```
this.validation.on(user).ensure('name').isNotEmpty()...
```

But how can I trigger validation in activate method? I have tried

```
this.validation.validate();
```

but the fields in the form don't change (validation errors are not displayed). 
Only when I start typing the validation messages are displayed on the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`activate` happens in the lifecycle before the form (viewmodel) is attached to the DOM.  Try calling the method like you were in the `attached` callback and see how you go.

the lifcycle order I am aware of is:

- created
- canActivate
- activate
- bind
- attached
- canDeactivate
- deactivate
- detached
- unbind

Comment: Thank you, I have moved it to attached and I works now